# Best way to create a list item

Tags: html, css

I'm new in html/css.
I need to implement a simple list item with a text on the left side and an icon on the right side.
This is the current result:
[image]
[image]

It works but I'm not sure I implemented it in the right way.
This is the html code:

```
<div>
    <div class="default-list-item-text row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Exampe 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            11111111111111
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right default-list-item-icon"></i>
</div>
```

And these are the css classes:

```
.default-list-item-text
{
    width:calc(100% - 40px); 
    padding:16px;
}

.default-list-item-icon
{
    position:absolute; 
    right:16px; 
    top:14px;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#A9A9A9;
}
```

As you can see I set the with of the text field to 100% - 40px, then I set the icon as absolute and right 16px.
But I dont like this solution because if I need to add a second icon on the right I have to edit the width of the text field, 
then play with absolute positions and right:left:.
Is there a dinamically way to achieve this without javascript?
In Android I would use toLeftOf, is there an equivalent thing in css?

Furthermore if the text grow in 2 or more lines the right image does not center vertically.
[image]

So, what is the best way to implement such list item?
(if possible, I would avoid 'float')

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox would seem to be optimal:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-top: 75px;
  /* for demo */
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.col-md-6 {
  flex: 1
}
.default-list-item-icon {
  padding: 16px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parent">
  <div class="default-list-item-text row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Example
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      11111111111111
    </div>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right default-list-item-icon"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: 1 hour after posting this answer, I realize you want to avoid "float"!
Hence I'm sorry for the above suggestion... though sure it's the most directly related with your kind of issue.

---

You might use `float` to get rid of further complications when adding new icons, like this:
*Warning: to really see the result you must switch to "Full page", because the "Full page" box hides the rightmost pseudo-icon!*

```css
.default-list-item-text {
  padding:16px;
  float: left;
}
.default-list-item-icon {
  float: right;
  padding: 14px 16px 0 0;
  font-size:22px;
  color:#A9A9A9;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="default-list-item-text row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Exampe 
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    11111111111111
  </div>
</div>
  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right default-list-item-icon">AAA</i>
  <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right default-list-item-icon">BBB</i>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Notes:

- consequently, you must protect following code with `clear: both;`, as you can see in the example
- more widely, look at all general information available to learn about the multiple side effects that may happen depending on other code wrapping this reduced example!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ul and li tag for creating the list.

```css
.default-list-item-text
{
    width:calc(100% - 40px); 
    padding:16px;
}

.default-list-item-icon
{
    position:absolute; 
    right:16px; 
    top:14px;
    font-size:22px;
    color:#A9A9A9;
}

li{
 list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>
   <li>
      <div class="default-list-item-text row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              Exampe 
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              11111111111111
          </div>
      </div>
      <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right default-list-item-icon"></i>
    </li>
       <li>
      <div class="default-list-item-text row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              Exampe 
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              11111111111111
          </div>
      </div>
      <i class="mdi mdi-arrow-right default-list-item-icon"></i>
    </li>

</ul>
```